# Mono System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException when running on Linux

Tags: .net, jboss, mono

I am using mono 2.10.2 to run a .Net application on RHEL 5. The application has a reference assembly Dll which makes a web service call to a JBoss server.I get **'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'** when i run it in RHEL.I installed mono on windows and it runs fine there.The client application uses a .p12 certificate

I run the program with the following command:

```
mono --debug --trace=N:MyApplication "Prod_Module/TestApp/bin/Debug/abc Prod Module Test.exe"
```

I get the following trace while running it:

> [0x40570940:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Store Root
>   doesn't exists. [0x40570940:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Store Root
>   doesn't exists. [0x42155940:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error. [0x40fd8940:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error. [0x2b15fbbefb50:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username").
>   Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password> [0x2b15fbbefb50:]
>   EXCEPTION handling: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling
>   Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/",
>   local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>
>   [0x2b15fbbefb50:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username").
>   Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password> [0x2b15fbbefb50:]
>   EXCEPTION handling: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling
>   Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/",
>   local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>
>   [0x2b15fbbefb50:] EXCEPTION handling:
>   abc.Prod.Module.Exception_Model.ModulePluginException: Unmarshalling
>   Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/",
>   local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>
>   Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username"). Expected
>   elements are <{}username>,<{}password>
>
> The JBoss(v7.1) server logs has the following:
>
> 01:26:09,038 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-3506-1) Interceptor for
>   {http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/}ArrayWSAPIImplService#{http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/}login
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username"). Expected
>   elements are <{}username>,<{}password>    at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:642)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
>     at
>   org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
>   [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_27] Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/",
>   local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>]
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:434)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:371)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:778)
>     ... 29 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username").
>   Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:251)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:498)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:480)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:247)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:181)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
>     ... 31 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected
>   element (uri:"http://ws.array.asi.abc.com/", local:"username").
>   Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>   ... 42 more

Is it something to do with the client certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the certificates yourself, as stated by [Mono Security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Security#Secure_Socket_Layer_.28SSL.29_.2F_Transport_Layer_Security_.28TLS.29).

Comment: Thankyou ! I was able to import the certificate using
certmgr -ssl https://10.10.6.74:8443/array_ws/MyService?WSDL