# C# Couldn't decode XML

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I am having a problem where my C# program running in Mono on a Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux gives an error when I try to make it load a key from an XML string or file. It can encrypt and decrypt a message when I tell it to generated its own keys but if I were to take the exact same XML of the generated keys gotten from ToXmlString and give them to it through FromXmlString then it complains about "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographyException: Couldn't decode XML...".

I should mention that providing any code is probably useless because the exact same code works perfectly when run on Windows or my Arch Linux desktop, the issue obviously has something to do with the ARM Mono implementation for the RPi which after a quick version check is said to be V2 (I have updated it just now) whereas my desktop Arch Linux has V4.

I would therefore like to know if anyone knows of a workaround for this or could report it as a bug to the Mono developers.

EDIT:
Here is the full console output:

Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Couldn't decode XML ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Private/public key mismatch
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString (System.String xmlString) [0x00000] in :0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString (System.String xmlString) [0x00000] in :0
  at PHPEncryptTest.RSA.EncryptData (System.String strData2Encrypt) [0x00000] in :0
  at PHPEncryptTest.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Couldn't decode XML ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Private/public key mismatch
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.RSAManaged.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters (RSAParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString (System.String xmlString) [0x00000] in :0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString (System.String xmlString) [0x00000] in :0
  at PHPEncryptTest.RSA.EncryptData (System.String strData2Encrypt) [0x00000] in :0
  at PHPEncryptTest.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0):

I have been running mono on RPI for a while now, but i have not gone into the security namespace, since mono best supported on linux and they are porting (lose words) the .Net framework to fit linux we can always expect some bugs, especially when namespaces as security,
check out: [Mono System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException when running on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082571/mono-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-when-running-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that question us rely all that relevant in regards to this one